# What is the difference between document.scrollingElement.scrollHeight and document.body.scrollHeight?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

`document.scrollingElement.scrollHeight` and `document.body.scrollHeight`?  The latter seems to be consistently smaller than the former, but I don't know why. I would expect that they are equal. Why aren't they?

Comment: Why would they be the same? scrollingElement should be `<html>`, not body.

Comment: @Kaiido  Sorry not too sure what you mean, what do you mean that scrollingElement should be `<html>`? Sorry I'm new to this.

Comment: type `console.log(document.scrollingElement)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're not the same element.

```
console.log(document.scrollingElement.tagName) // HTML
console.log(document.body.tagName) // BODY
```

The reason `document.body.scrollHeight` is smaller is because `<body>` usually has a margin by default.